# Pickle Error when loading an object in python?

Tags: python, stream, deserialization, pickle, dill

When I try to load a file in python I get this error from dill:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LArSoftSGD.py", line 154, in <module>
    stat_bundle = train_batch_iterator(clf, TOTAL_TRAINED_EVENTS)
  File "LArSoftSGD.py", line 121, in train_batch_iterator
    plot_data.append((test_batch_iterator(clf), tte))
  File "LArSoftSGD.py", line 91, in test_batch_iterator
    minibatch_test = dill.load(stream)
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 199, in load
obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py", line 1036, in load
dispatch[key[0]](self)
KeyError: 95
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong?
Here is some of my code where the error happened:

```
for file in glob.glob('./SerializedData/Batch8202015_1999/*'):
    with open(file, 'rb') as stream:
        minibatch_test = dill.load(stream)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  This does not seem to be a serialization error, it's most likely a coding error.

Essentially, the dispatch is a dictionary of pickled object types and their pickling functions, with the keys being object types.  You have a `95` as a key… which is definitely not what the `dispatch` expects.

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dill.pickle_dispatch_copy
{<type 'unicode'>: <function save_unicode at 0x10c8f1cf8>, <type 'dict'>: <function save_dict at 0x10c8f1f50>, <type 'int'>: <function save_int at 0x10c8f1b18>, <type 'long'>: <function save_long at 0x10c8f1b90>, <type 'list'>: <function save_list at 0x10c8f1e60>, <type 'str'>: <function save_string at 0x10c8f1c80>, <type 'function'>: <function save_global at 0x10c8f5140>, <type 'instance'>: <function save_inst at 0x10c8f50c8>, <type 'type'>: <function save_global at 0x10c8f5140>, <type 'NoneType'>: <function save_none at 0x10c8f1a28>, <type 'bool'>: <function save_bool at 0x10c8f1aa0>, <type 'tuple'>: <function save_tuple at 0x10c8f1d70>, <type 'float'>: <function save_float at 0x10c8f1c08>, <type 'classobj'>: <function save_global at 0x10c8f5140>, <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>: <function save_global at 0x10c8f5140>}
```

You have something like this:

```
>>> key = [95]
>>> dispatch = {}
>>> dispatch[key[0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 95
```

Your code to load the pickled object looks fine… however, and while that might be where the error is being thrown, it's not where the bug *actual is*.
There's not enough information from what you've given above to uncover that.